# c# - What is the best way to split string in multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I am using `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails` method to fetch files from the FTP server.

The string format is: `11-02-16 11:33AM abc.xml\r\n11-02-16 11:35AM xyz.xml`

I am able to store `11-02-16 11:33AM abc.xml` in a array.

How can i store the date and file name in an array.

*I don't want to enumerate the whole array and split each value again.*

Comment: Create a new class with all required properties and store an array of it.

Comment: is this the format you always going to get .. 11-02-16 11:35AM<space>xyz.xml

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `Dictionary<DateTime, string>`;

```
List<string> splits = "yourSplitsStringArray".ToList();

//Create your Result Dictionary
Dictionary<DateTime, string> result = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();

//Process your data:
splits.ForEach(x => result.Add(DateTime.Parse(x.Substring(0, 16)), x.Substring(17, x.Length - 17)));
```

Regarding your string:

```
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|
|1|1|-|0|2|-|1|6| |1| 1| :| 3| 3| A| M| a| b| c| .| x| m| l|
```

So your DateTime starts at `[0]` with a total lenght of `16` => `x.Substring(0, 16)`.

Your filename start at `[17]` with and is `x.Lenght - 17` chars long.

I know you don't want to enumerate all of em again, but I think it's the most simple and practical way to achieve what you need.

You could also include part of my answer into your first splitting operation.

**BUT:**

Since it's a Dictionary the **Key** which is the `DateTime` has to be unique.
So if you aren't sure if that's gonna be the case, use `List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>` instead. It's similar to a Dictionary.

This will change your `Linq` to:

```
//Process your data:
splits.ForEach(x => result.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, string>(DateTime.Parse(x.Substring(0, 16)), x.Substring(17, x.Length - 17))));
```